# Draw a network of nodes

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graph-theory

There is a network of up to 26 nodes (named `A` to `Z` or `a` to `z` as per your wish). Every pair of nodes may be connected or disconnected. A node may be connected to at most 4 other nodes. Your task is to draw the network in a 2D diagram. Input will be given such that this task is possible (see more constraints in output section).

---

**Format**

**Input**

- Pairs of letters (`A` to `Z` or `a` to `z` as per your wish). They are not sorted in any order.
- Optional - number of pairs

**Output**

- An ASCII drawing that shows the actual links between the nodes. Nodes are given by `a` to `z` or `A` to `Z`. Use `-` for horizontal links and `|` for vertical links. Links may be of any (non-zero) length but they should be straight horizontal/vertical lines *that do not bend*. Spaces can be added provided they don't disfigure the picture.

You may not use built-ins that help in layout of the graph. Other graph-related built-ins may be allowed (though solutions without built-ins would be more appreciated). Shortest code wins.

---

**Sample data**

**Input**

```
A B
B F
B L
F K
L K
K R
K S
R P
S J
S P
J A
T V
V N
```

**Output**

```
A - B - F   T - V
|   |   |       |
|   L - K - R   N
|       |   |
J ----- S - P
```

**Input**

```
H C
G H
A B
B F
B C
F G
C D
D A
```

**Output**

```
A - B ----- F
|   |       |
D - C - H - G
```

Comment: I consider that my previous questions have been sufficiently answered, but note that the new test case is wrong because the first line is `H A` and that edge isn't in the given output. Edit: problem identified and fixed.

Comment: Maybe change it to "First (working) code wins"? ;-) Seriously, this is challenging on its own, even without golfing...

Comment: @Marco13 That would most likely get the challenge closed as off topic.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Please don't use flags to ask moderators questions. If you need feedback on something, there's always [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: @Dennis ok, sorry. I've never been on chat before, so I don't know how it works.

Comment: Just click the link, click *logged in* at the bottom of the page, log in as you usual do, and go back to the chat page.

Comment: Will there always be at least one edge? Can there be isolated vertices? Can a node be connected to itself with an edge?

Comment: @mbomb007 Isolated vertices don't have to be outputted (like in the examples). A node cannot be connected to itself. Your code doesn't need to work for empty input.

Comment: "Never mind the golfing requirement for now." Regardless of the difficulty of the answer, answers still need to follow the rules, part of which are that all answers need to make at least an attempt at golfing the code. Please don't encourage people to do otherwise.

Comment: @MartinEnder Ok then, if you say so. Btw why are non-golfing coding questions not allowed on this site? And which site would they be better to put on?

Comment: They just have a different tag. Like [code-challenge], [king-of-the-hill], [code-bowling], etc

Comment: @mbomb007 Ik. But still it isn't as well accepted if I submit it as code-challenge

Comment: It depends how you submit it. But for the most part that's because it needs an objective winning criterion, and the easiest one is byte-count. Any other criterion is likely to be seen as inferior.

Comment: @mbomb007 Why isn't 'first working solution' an objective criterion?

Comment: It is, but only one submission gets to compete. So if you're not first, what's the point in trying?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code what about crossings/overlaps, e.g. `ad,bd,cd,ae,be,ce,af,bf,cf`

Comment: @Rod Input will be given such that there's always atleast one way to draw it.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 142

You didn't ask for an optimal, deterministic or fast solution, so here you go:

```
qN%Sf%::c_s_&:Aff#:E;{A{;[DmrDmr]2f*}%:C;E{Cf=~.-:*}%0m1{E{Cf=$~1$.-_:g:T\:+,1>\ff*\f.+T0="-|"=f+~}%CA.++:L2f<__&=!}?}gS25*a25*L{~2$4$=\tt}/N*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%25Sf%25%3A%3Ac_s_%26%3AAff%23%3AE%3B%7BA%7B%3B%5BDmrDmr%5D2f*%7D%25%3AC%3BE%7BCf%3D%7E.-%3A*%7D%250m1%7BE%7BCf%3D%24%7E1%24.-_%3Ag%3AT%5C%3A%2B%2C1%3E%5Cff*%5Cf.%2BT0%3D%22-%7C%22%3Df%2B%7E%7D%25CA.%2B%2B%3AL2f%3C__%26%3D!%7D%3F%7DgS25*a25*L%7B%7E2%244%24%3D%5Ctt%7D%2FN*&input=A%20X%0AX%20Y%0AT%20X)

This generates random coordinates for each letter and tests if the layout is acceptable (edge letters lining up and no intersections), until it is. It gets mind-numbingly slow as you add more edges.

The two `D` letters in the code specify the maximum x and y coordinates; I picked `D` (=13) because I think it should be sufficient for all cases, feel free to prove me wrong. But you can change them to other values to speed up the program, e.g. the 2nd example should finish within a minute or two if you use 3 and 4 instead.

Comment: I didn't ask for a fast solution, but maybe I should have asked for a deterministic one. But now that the question has been up for so long, I won't change it.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code it shouldn't be too hard to make it deterministic - try all combinations of coordinates. But it would probably be longer and much slower, and eat a lot of memory too.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 813 bytes

```c++
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<cstdlib>
typedef int I;typedef char*C;I a,t,s,h;struct p{I x,y;}j,k;std::map<I,std::set<I>>l;std::map<I,p>g;C m,M="  |-";I L(I n,C q,C Q){j=g[n],h=1;for(I o:l[n])if(g.find(o)!=g.end())if(!(a=(k=g[o]).y==j.y)&&k.x^j.x)h=0;else for(I x=j.x,y=j.y,e=k.y*s+k.x,b,d=(k.x<j.x||k.y<j.y)?-1:1;a?x+=d:y+=d,(b=y*s+x)^e;m[b]=q[a])if(m[b]^Q[a]){h=0;break;}}I N(){for(auto i:g)for(I n:l[i.first])if(g.find(n)==g.end())return n;for(auto i:l)if(g.find(a=i.first)==g.end())return a;exit(puts(m));}I f(){for(I n=N(),x,y=0,b;y<s;y+=2)for(x=0;x<s;x+=2)m[b=y*s+x]==*M?g[n]={x,y},m[b]=n,L(n,M+2,M),h&&f(),L(n,M,M+2),m[b]=*M,g.erase(n):0;}I main(I c,C*v){for(;--c;l[a].insert(s),l[s].insert(a))a=v[c][0],s=v[c][1];t=l.size(),s=t|1;memset(m=(C)calloc(s,s),*M,s*s-1);for(a=1;a<s;++a)m[a*s-1]=10;f();}
```

Takes input as commandline arguments, e.g.:

```sh
./network AB BF BL FK LK KR KS RP SJ SP JA TV VN
```

Nowhere near competitive with aditsu's answer by size, but much more efficient!

This will brute-force all possible solutions, but will quickly recognise failure as it goes. For the two test cases, it finishes almost immediately, and it seems to only take a few seconds on more awkward inputs. It also has no limitation to the accepted node names (though you can't name one space, `|` or `-`) and has no limit on the number of nodes (as long as all names fit in a byte, so the practical limit is 252 nodes, and it will get slow long before reaching that many).

There's plenty of scope for speeding this up; a lot of short-circuit exiting was lost to the golfing, and there's parts which could be moved out of hot-loops. Also some observations of symmetry can dramatically reduce the positioning of the first 2 nodes, among other things.

---

Breakdown:

```c++
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<cstdlib>
typedef int I;
typedef char*C;
I a,t,s,h;                // Variables shared between functions
struct p{I x,y;}          // Coord datatype
j,k;                      // Temporary coord references
std::map<I,std::set<I>>l; // Bidirectional multimap of node links
std::map<I,p>g;           // Map of nodes to positions
C m,                      // Rendered grid
M="  |-";                 // Lookup table for output characters

// Line rendering function
// Sets h to 1 if all lines are drawn successfully, or 0 if there is a blocker
I L(I n,C q,C Q){
  j=g[n],h=1;
  for(I o:l[n])                  // For each connection to the current node
    if(g.find(o)!=g.end())       // If the target node has been positioned
      if(!(a=(k=g[o]).y==j.y)&&k.x^j.x)h=0; // Fail if the nodes are not aligned
      else
        for(I x=j.x,y=j.y,             // Loop from node to target
          e=k.y*s+k.x,
          b,d=(k.x<j.x||k.y<j.y)?-1:1;
          a?x+=d:y+=d,(b=y*s+x)^e;
          m[b]=q[a])                   // Render character (| or -)
          if(m[b]^Q[a]){h=0;break;}    // Abort if cell is not blank
}

// Next node selection: finds the next connected node to try,
// or the next unconnected node if the current connected set is complete.
// Displays the result and exits if the entire graph has been rendered.
I N(){
  for(auto i:g)for(I n:l[i.first])  // Search for a connected node...
    if(g.find(n)==g.end())return n; // ...and return the first available
  for(auto i:l)                     // Else search for an unconnected node...
    if(g.find(a=i.first)==g.end())
      return a;                     // ...and return the first available
  exit(puts(m));                    // Else draw the grid to screen and stop
}

// Recursive brute-force implementation
I f(){
  for(I n=N(),x,y=0,b;y<s;y+=2) // Loop through all grid positions
    for(x=0;x<s;x+=2)
      m[b=y*s+x]==*M            // If the current position is available
       ?g[n]={x,y},             // Record the location for this node
        m[b]=n,                 // Render the node
        L(n,M+2,M),             // Render lines to connected nodes
        h&&f(),                 // If line rendering succeeded, recurse
        L(n,M,M+2),             // Un-render lines
        m[b]=*M,g.erase(n)      // Un-render node
       :0;
}

// Input parsing and grid setup
I main(I c,C*v){
  // Parse all inputs into a bidirectional multi-map
  for(;--c;l[a].insert(s),l[s].insert(a))a=v[c][0],s=v[c][1];
  t=l.size(),s=t|1; // Calculate a grid size
  // Allocate memory for the grid and render newlines
  memset(m=(C)calloc(s,s),*M,s*s-1);
  for(a=1;a<s;++a)m[a*s-1]=10;
  f(); // Begin recursive solving
}
```

Comment: Finally! It's been 2 months. I personally am not in favour for golfing such an answer, I was only required to, by the people of this site.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code if you don't want code golf there are plenty of other objective winning criteria you can use (though obviously, you can't change this challenge now it's been posted). Time-based examples would be: fastest to generate results on specific hardware (e.g. particular EC2 instance / raspberry pi / etc.), most compact output for a battery of tests within a time limit, largest network supported from a battery of tests within a time limit (e.g. a day, allowing flexibility on the specific hardware). Try using the sandbox next time; people can help you pick an objective.

Comment: [746 bytes](https://pastebin.com/GGpyFdf3)